# Not receiving network data with android?

Tags: java, android, network-programming

this is my ConnectionThread for Android
i have been trying for a few hours but i am unable to send data from my computer to my app that i am making.. any help would be amazing.. just comment if you need to know anything more.. no exceptions are being thrown and i know a connection is being made..

```
public class ConnectionThread implements Runnable {

private final int PORT = 4567;
private static PrintWriter out = null;
private BufferedReader in = null;
Socket kkSocket = null;
String ip = "";
//LoginActivity a;

public ConnectionThread(/*LoginActivity a,*/String ip) {
     this.ip = ip;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        // this.a = a;
            kkSocket = new Socket(ip, PORT);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        //    a.makeToast("CONNECTION SUCCESS!!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(Auth.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        //  a.makeToast("UNABLE TO CONNECT TO:"+ ip);
            Log.e("PPChat", "UNABLE TO CONNECT");
        }
    String fromServer = null;
    try {
        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) == null) {
            Log.e("PP", "it happened...");
            FullscreenActivity.appendText(fromServer);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("READ ERROR", "was unable to read from the socket");
        //a.makeToast("was unable to read from the socket");
    }
    Log.e("PPChat", "connection is done");
}

public static boolean sendNetworkMessage(String str) {
    try{
    out.println(str);
    out.flush();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

this is the thread that sends the network data.. i know a connection is being made.. i think i am just making a simple error that i am not seeing..

```
public class ConnectionThread extends Thread{
private Socket socket = null;
private String inputLine;
public static PrintWriter out = null;
public ConnectionThread(Socket accept) {
    super("ConnectionThread");
    this.socket = accept;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
    System.out.println("connection made");
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("server recieved: " +inputLine);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println("thread is finished");
}
}
```

and here is where i actually send the data in a thread the gets the input from the user to send the data

```
public class InputThread extends Thread{

private Scanner sc = null;

public InputThread() {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        String temp = sc.nextLine();
        ConnectionThread.out.println(temp);
        System.out.println("i wrote that: "+temp);
    }
}

}
```

sorry if this is really easy.. im getting

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Android AsyncTask to do this kind for works.  I don't really know your exact requirement but normally to do this kind of background works it's recommended to use the AsyncTask. Please refer this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.